# Bulk creation of Azure management group

Tags: powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I am trying to run the below power shell-

```
New-AzManagementGroup -GroupName 'Contoso' -DisplayName 'Contoso Group' -ParentId /providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/Infra'
```

To automate the  task so that I can deploy it to the multiple management group in a hierarchy.
I have used the csv file to import the following fields `GroupName`  `DisplayName` and `Paraentid` but it looks like nothing is happening.
May be I am doing something  very silly or missing some syntax.
I have managed to create a simple powershell below-

```
$DataSheet = Import-Csv -path “xx.csv”
foreach($data in $DataSheet)
{
$GroupName=$data.GroupName
$DisplayName=$data.DisplayName
$ParentId=$data.ParentId
New-AzManagementGroup -GroupName $GroupName -DisplayName $DisplayName  -ParentId $ParentId
}
```

But how can I add some error trapping in this script and remove the requirement to put the full resource ID (-ParentId) which is quite long
This script is importing data from the excel which has three headers GroupName,DisplayName and ParentId.

Thanks,

Comment: For error trapping, you can put "New-AzManagementGroup xxx" to try-catch block. And for "remove the requirement to put the full resource ID", can you please explain more? If you don't provide the parentid in .csv file, then where you wanna get it?

Comment: @Ivan Yang thanks  your response, the parent-id and the error handling issue is resolved .Now my issue  is that if the parent group is not present the creation of new management group will fail with an error the parent group doesn't exists.What syntax, I can add to the power-shell so that it will first create the parent group, if it is not present (as per the excel data) and then carry- on with the creation of new management group i.e. child management group.Does it make any sense to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are able to read the CSV file and it's in the right format. With the below code snippet, I was able to read the CSV and create the child management groups. To avoid giving the Parent ID, again and again, you can get the parent object first and use that in your code.

The below code snippet should help.

```
$parentObject = Get-AzManagementGroup -GroupName "ParentGroup"
$DataSheet = Import-Csv -path "xx.csv"
foreach($data in $DataSheet)
{
   $GroupName=$data.GroupName
   $DisplayName=$data.DisplayName
   New-AzManagementGroup -GroupName $GroupName -DisplayName $DisplayName   
   -ParentObject $parentObject
}
```

Below is the data in CSV.

[image: csv table]

Hope the above information helps.

Comment: thanks for your response. But the Parent Id can be different for some child management group.The reason why I want to eliminate the need for adding parent ID in the excel due to its long resource name and to avoid any typo mistakes during its insertion.Please see the link below (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/management-groups/ ) for further information.Secondly, how can I add other function to capture any error occurred during the management group creation by the script.